# How many of my flags were invalid?

Tags: feature-request, flag-weight

The flag weight summary shows me how many posts I flagged and how many were marked as valid. However, since old posts are neither valid nor invalid, how can I tell how many flags were valid? Can we add this?

[image]

---

Edit: So apparently no news is good news. Could we show `"0 were marked as invalid"`?

Comment: Clearly none of yours were invalid. My summary says that "1 were marked invalid".

Comment: Definitely none. I get the same thing on Meta, where I have had no flags marked as invalid.

Comment: Some invalid flags aren't being recorded in this summary, at least for me. I've had a few recent drops in my flag weight, but no *"were marked as invalid"* flags recorded, unlike what Kate's seeing.

Comment: @Michael: That's probably a result of comment flags. They aren't included in the flagging history, but they do still affect your flag weight.